# How to validate Email if it is already used / or not in database? in ionic 3 Application

Tags: angular, validation, ionic3

Please share some knowledge on “How can we validate email with dynamic data coming from firebase?”

Here is my code I am stuck with this…

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserProvider } from '../providers/database/user/user';

export class EmailValidator {
  public users: any;
  public email: any;
  constructor(
    public _DBUSER: UserProvider
  ) {
    this.loadAndParseUsers();
  }
  loadAndParseUsers() {
    this.users = this._DBUSER.renderAllUsers();
    var allEmails = [];
    this.users.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      element.forEach(user => {
        allEmails.push(user.email);
      });
    });
    console.log(allEmails);

  }
  static checkEmail(control: FormControl): any {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      //Fake a slow response from server

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value == "adminh@gmail.com") {
          console.log(control.value);

          resolve({
            "Email taken": true
          });

        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 2000);

    });
  }
}
```

Static checking is working fine. But I am not able to check with dynamic email coming from database. I am quite newbie to Ionic please help. thanks

Comment: If i am not wrong ,you want check email is present in db or not, right?For that you can create Services and make a call of API, you can see here [https://blog.ionicframework.com/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api]

Comment: are you going to use forms like reactive forms  to handle enter new emails ??

Comment: @ Muhammad Albarmawi  I am using Ionic and for database firebase

Answer (score 1):

Well you are getting all the emails in the `loadAndParseUsers` method, so you can use that emails list to check if the new email already exists or not.

Let me say that in general is not a good idea getting every single email and looping till you find the one you are looking for. The better solution would be querying the database with the email you have so you don't load every single user into the app.

Still if you want to get all users and check with javascript this is how I would do it.

```
static loadAndParseUsers() {
        this.users = this._DBUSER.renderAllUsers();
        return this.users.reduce((state, element) => {
           return state.concat(element.map(user => user.email));
        }, []);
      }

      static checkEmail(control: FormControl): any {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          //Fake a slow response from server
          setTimeout(() => {
            const allEmail = EmailValidator.loadAndParseUsers();
            resolve({ "Email taken": allEmail.indexOf(control.value) !== -1 });
          }, 2000);
        });
      }
```

Comment: "Property 'loadAndParseUsers' does not exist on type 'typeof EmailValidator'.",
I am getting this error, Please help. **"check if the new email already exists or not"** I will do this once I get my code running. Thanks for your advice

Comment: I just realized that `checkEmail` is a static method, so you can't do `this.loadAndParseUsers`. You can check the change I did to the post

Comment: Now I am getting same error for this.users, _DBUSER inside loadAndParseUsers function. Please help..and what I am doing wrong, is their any guide line about this . please advice..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checking email requied sent http request to database and rest api that going th check if the email existin the database or not .

for this case is better to create async validator to handle this kind of tasks, you can read the article about below about how to create async validator and connect to database

[Custom Async Validators in Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/)